# Maximizing WPF Doesn't Update Width?

Tags: wpf, resize, width, maximize, maximize-window

The `Width` property of the screen doesn't seem to update to the fully maximized width when maximizing a window.  If I resize it everything works fine, but not when maximizing.

The code I have is as follows:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateColumns();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateColumns();
}

private void UpdateColumns()
{
    ColumnCount = Math.Round(Width/150);
    statusBarItemColumnCount.Content = ColumnCount;
    button1.Content = ColumnCount + " " + Width;
}

private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateColumns();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at `ActualWidth`, rather than `Width`.

Comment: Good fix.  Any idea why the normal width wouldn't work though?

Answer (score 3):

try using `ActualWidth` instead of `Width`, that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of any code that needs width and height:

**var RealWidth = Math.Max(Width,ActualWidth);**

**var RealHeight = Math.Max(Width,ActualHeight);**

Then use RealWidth and RealHeight variables because they will always be right.

***During Construction and before Showing ActualWidth and ActualHeight will be zero so Width and Height will be used.***

***After Maximizing Width and Height are still the pre-Maximized values but ActualWidth and ActualHeight will be used because they are larger.***

If you followed all that and you want an elegant solution make two properties.

```
   private double RealWidth
    {
        get { return Math.Max(Width, ActualWidth); }
    }
    private double RealHeight
    {
        get { return Math.Max(Height, ActualHeight); }
    }
```

Then you can use RealWidth and RealHeight in all situations.
Make the properties Internal or Public if you will need them outside the class.

Happy Programming Everybody!!!!!